# Special characters in email from Oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, email, plsql, special-characters

I try to send an email using utl_smtp with Oracle including norwegian characters (å æ ø). The characters are stored and displayed correctly in the database otherwise, but shows up as question marks in the email.

My database character set is WE8MSWIN1252

I have tried different Content-Type mime headers in the email including 'text/plain; charset="win-1252"', this does not seem to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default smtp is 7bit ascii (kinda old tech :). You must be using `UTL_SMTP.write_data` and from the [documentation](http://download-uk.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_smtp.htm#i1004100):

> Text (VARCHAR2) data sent using
>   `WRITE_DATA` is converted to US7ASCII
>   before it is sent. If the text
>   contains multibyte characters, each
>   multibyte character in the text that
>   cannot be converted to US7ASCII is
>   replaced by a '?' character. If
>   8BITMIME extension is negotiated with
>   the SMTP server using the EHLO
>   subprogram, multibyte VARCHAR2 data
>   can be sent by first converting the
>   text to RAW using the `UTL_RAW` package,
>   and then sending the RAW data using
>   `WRITE_RAW_DATA`.

There is a [sample demo package on OTN](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/pl_sql/htdocs/Utl_Smtp_Sample.html) that shows how to send multibyte emails.